# WPF Parent UserControl cannot locate resource, thats beeing used in child UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I stumble upon two exceptions in one part of a problem. But, I decided this one is more important than the other and it gets me a bit confused, so i would appreciate any help in getting rid off this error.

In summary - I have a user control displayed to the user, that has `TabControl`. To each `TabItem` i had added other `UserControls`. One of such controls displays xaml resources to display images (converted them from to SVG and then to xaml as regular PNG/etc resolution didn't look good). Same resource displays ok on 'original' `UserControl`, and using both path, and pack uri (this is the same assembly) seems to find & display resource when i need to. Unfortunately, when i reference `UserControl` that uses hence resource in parent `UserControl` it throws an Error - **'*XDG0062 Cannot locate resource 'global%20objects/pictures/user%20controls/icon.xaml'*'** as well as on the grandparent (original) `UserControl` that actually uses same resource successfully.

After debugging the code and during rebuilds i do not get errors and both are not interrupted, but it keeps reoccuring.

I am trying to display minimal amount of code to the thing that actually seens to be broken.

**ICON: (Oracle)**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Viewbox xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Stretch="Uniform"
             x:Key="Icon">
        <Canvas Name="svg16" Width="512.000000" Height="512.000000">
            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <Canvas.Resources/>
            <Canvas Name="g14">
                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.100000" ScaleY="-0.100000"/>
                        <TranslateTransform X="0.000000" Y="512.000000"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path12" Fill="DarkRed">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <PathGeometry Figures="M1440 4169 c-257 -30 -504 -120 -725 -266 -137 -91 -347 -301 -438 -438 -499 -756 -304 -1749 443 -2250 219 -147 462 -234 735 -265 121 -13 2089 -13 2210 0 561 63 1035 390 1282 885 263 525 224 1133 -104 1630 -91 137 -301 347 -438 438 -228 150 -466 236 -740 267 -111 12 -2117 11 -2225 -1z m2173 -574 c621 -94 1021 -708 856 -1316 -30 -113 -118 -282 -197 -379 -162 -200 -401 -336 -659 -375 -145 -22 -1961 -22 -2106 0 -263 40 -499 174 -663 379 -75 93 -164 266 -193 375 -65 239 -44 496 59 718 148 317 447 544 788 598 134 20 1977 21 2115 0z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
            </Canvas>
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Grand parent UserControl : Resources**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="\global objects\pictures\user controls\Icon.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

**Grand parent UserControl : TabControl**
Here im getting error on 2nd item  `<local:ManualMatch/>` , but same icon for displaying as header is fine.

```
            <TabItem>
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Width="auto"
                                Height="auto">
                        <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource Icon}"
                                        Width="50"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TabItem.Header>
                <!--element not important-->
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem>
                <local:ManualMatch Margin="0 20"/>
            </TabItem>
```

**Parent UserControl : ScrollViewer**
here i am using another usercontrol that references same icon resource. The error written above is thrown at `DataTemplate`. The resource is not added here, but i tried that, didn't help at all.

```
    <ScrollViewer>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PossibleMatches}">
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:ManualMatchItem/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

**Grandchild/Lowest UserControl: Resources**
Here I tried PackUri as well as regular path, both work correctly and display item, but error reoccurs.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="\global objects\pictures\user controls\Icon.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

**Grandchild/Lowest UserControl: ContentControl**
This also work correctly, and like stated above everything is displayed, but error reoccurs.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource Icon}"
                    Width="35"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: One problem there is you have pieces of ui as resources. That's a bad idea. You can only use them in one place at a time that way. it's a vrry clunky implementation you've got there as well. You should put geometries in resources instead. Use these as the data of paths where you want each icon.

Comment: Out of interest, what do you mean by "clunky implementation", cause as i stated those are parts of the xaml. I assume you talking about icon implementation? Could you direct me  to what you mean :)

Comment: `Viewbox` is an control. looks you're try to use `Viewbox`+`Canvas`+`Path` create a vector graphics of a icon and use it in several places.  But having "control" as "resource" is generally a bad idea. Because the resource are usually "reusable" by design, but control have a parent, it can only stay in one place in a time, control cannot reusable. Try change it to `DrawingBrush`+`GeometryDrawing`. Both the pros and cons of WPF are "all roads lead to Rome" - But there are too many roads, and some of them ware wrong.

Comment: I follow up on that advice, but i still get same error it's just makes xaml more readable :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found a solution for exception, although as per advices i also switched from `ViewBox`, `Canvas`, `Path` to `DrawingBrush` and `DrawingGroup`.

Although still not sure why exception occurs, when i moved Grand Child `UserControl` to `ResourceDictionary` the error was cleared. I also did forgot to use `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` but adding it had no effect on error.

```
    <ScrollViewer>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PossibleMatches}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource ManualMatchItem}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
```